# Blender: Find and delete disabled fcurves

Tags: python, animation, blender

I'm trying to write a script that iterates through the fcurves of an object and if it finds disabled ones, deletes them (The channels that have a red underline in the graph editor)

This seems to be one of the aspects of Blender's API that is somewhat shrouded in darkness for I couldn't find anything relevant anywhere.

What I mean by a disabled fcurve refers to the ones that are no longer connected to anything, like a deleted constraint with an animated parameter.

fcurve.users is just not relevant and returns an error :(

```
import bpy


for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.animation_data is not None:       
        for fcurve in obj.animation_data.action.fcurves:
            if len(fcurve.users) == 1:
                strip.action.fcurves.remove(fcurve)
```

I tried this but to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

'users' is a property of 'obj.animation_data.action', but not of 'fcurve'...

You can test "obj.animation_data.action.users == 1"

fcurve properties are here (I used 'dir' function to get it) :

```
__doc__
__module__
__slots__
array_index
auto_smoothing
bl_rna
color
color_mode
convert_to_keyframes
convert_to_samples
data_path
driver
evaluate
extrapolation
group
hide
is_empty
is_valid
keyframe_points
lock
modifiers
mute
range
rna_type
sampled_points
select
update
update_autoflags

for d in sorted(dir(fcurve)):
   print(d)
```